# Can the IBAN of the initiator of a SEPA direct debit be faked?

Tags: banks, money

I am living in Germany and when you get a phone call the phone number of the caller on the display can be faked. For example you can get a call from 110 (police phone number) but it's a scam. And that happens often in my area.

I wonder if the same applies to the IBAN of the initiator of a SEPA direct debit.

Let's say I see a direct debit from Amazon on my bank account statement. It shows the IBAN of Amazon which I know well from older direct debits. Is it safe this direct debit is really from Amazon or could it be literally anyone on earth?

I want to add that in Germany you only need the IBAN of someone to buy in an online shop. There is no technical protection like on PayPal where you have to allow direct debits. That's why it's neccessary to regularly check the bank account statement.